# Optimising a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to complete the below task in Python:

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/C

I created a simple script for it as can be seen below, but it returns a runtime error for the 7th test. I believe this is due to perhaps the code is taking too long, so I require assistance optimising it. I have looked at map and filter commands and tried implementing them, without success.

```
a=int(input())
entered_usernames=[]
n=0
while n<a:
    y=input()
    entered_usernames.append(y)
    n+=1

valid_usernames=[]
for i in entered_usernames:
    if i not in valid_usernames:
        valid_usernames.append(i)
        print('OK')
    else:
        count=1
        while i+str(count) in valid_usernames:
            count+=1
        valid_usernames.append(i+str(count))
        print(i+str(count))
```

Comment: What is the error? post the entire error

Comment: while i in valid_usernames than print  i+count

Comment: This type of exercises is usually for students to use hash tables, called dictionnaries in python. see @zwer response.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing `valid_usernames` to a `set` instead of a `list`.

For a list `list_a` operation `x in list_a` takes (on average) **linear time**.

For a set `set_a` operation `x in set_a` takes (on average) **constant time**.

(source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

This simple change could improve runtime a bit.

What also strikes me as potentially very slow is this fragment:

```
while i+str(count) in valid_usernames:
        count+=1
```

However, if you want to improve this, you need to think about using a completely different data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a lookup [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with a counter and solve this in O(N) time?

```
total = int(input())  # get the first input (total usernames)
database = {}  # our 'database' / lookup dict
candidates = [input() for _ in range(total)]  # pick usernames from the input
for candidate in candidates:  # loop through each candidate
    if candidate in database:  # already used, print with a counter
        print(candidate + str(database[candidate]))
        database[candidate] += 1  # increase the counter
    else:  # the candidate doesn't exist in the 'database'...
        print("OK")
        database[candidate] = 1  # initialize counter for the next time
```

Comment: this is probably the best solution, storing the number of occurrences instead of the names themselves

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
valid_usernames.append(i+str(valid_usernames.count(i)))
print(i+str(valid_usernames.count(i))
```